# sed delete all the words before a match

Tags: text-processing, sed

I want to delete all the words before a pattern for example: I want to delete all the words before `STAC`.

Input:

```
asd
asdd
asddd
STAC
asd
as
```

Output:

```
STAC
asd
as
```

I have this code `sed -ni "s/^.*STAC//d" myfile`

Comment: If a line has that word it doesn't matter, you just have to eliminate everything that is before that precise word, that is, STAC no HAYSTACK or any combination. Just STAC

Comment: thanks for the comment. I just modified the input

Comment: `awk '/^STAC$/,0'`, `awk '$0=="STAC",0'`, `grep -A100000 '^STAC$'`

Answer (score 14):

`sed` works linewise, that's why your try will not work.

So how to do it with `sed`? Define an address range, starting from the `STAC` line (`/^STAC$/`) to the end of the file (`$`). Those should be printed, so everything else (`!`) should get `d`eleted:

```
sed -i '/^STAC$/,$!d' myfile
```

Comment: Also possible: `sed -ni '/^STAC$/,$p' myfile`

Comment: This is for GNU `sed` only.

Comment: @Christopher Indeed, the `-i` option requires an argument (extension) for BSD `sed` and is not part of the standard. While the OP obviously uses GNU `sed`, your remark is valuable for future readers, so thank you!

Answer (score 8):

An `awk` variant which prints all lines after the match (including the match):

```
$ awk '/^STAC$/ { out=1 } out' file
STAC
asd
as
```

This matches the line that only contains the string `STAC` and sets `out` to a non-zero value.  For *each* line, if `out` is non-zero, print it.

Use `$0 == "STAC"` instead of `/^STAC$/` to do a string comparison instead of a regular expression match.

---

Slightly more obfuscated but shorter, using the boolean result of the match with the regular expression as an integer (will be 0 for a non-match, and 1 for a match):

```
awk 'p += /^STAC$/' file
```

If the result in `p` is non-zero, which it will be from the point where the regular expression first matches, the current line will be printed.

Use `p += ($0 == "STAC")` instead of `p += /^STAC$/` to do a string comparison instead of a regular expression match.

Answer (score 7):

Another option would be to use a scriptable editor like `ed`:

```
printf '%s\n' '1,/^STAC/-1 d' 'wq' | ed -s myfile
```

This prints two commands to `ed`:

- delete lines from 1 through (the line before the one that starts with `STAC`)
- write the file back to disk and quit

The `-s` option inhibits `ed`'s default printing of the number of bytes read & written.

Answer (score 3):

Using `awk`:

```
awk '/^STAC$/,/$ /' input
```

This will print all lines between `STAC` and anything (including the matching lines)

---

Or using a `grep` that supports the `-z` option (BSD grep does not):

> Treat input and output data as sequences of lines, each terminated by a zero byte (the ASCII NUL character) instead of a newline.

```
grep -z 'STAC' input
```

Answer (score 0):

`grep -wn STAC file.txt  | cut  -d":" -f 1 | xargs -I %  sed '1,%d' file.txt`

Get line number of the word, pass it to xargs and use sed to delete.